# Use jquery,backbone,underscore using requirejs globally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I tried with following code to include my custom js file using require js

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 0,
    paths: {
       underscore: 'underscore/underscore',
       backbone: "backbone/backbone-min",
        jquery: "jquery/jquery-min",
        customhandler: "jquery/customhandler"
    },
    shim: {
         underscore: {
           deps: ['underscore'],
           exports: '_'
        }
    }
});
```

Created separate file `customhandler.js` and inside i want to use backbone,jquery,underscore

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone'], function($,_,Backbone) {
    //using jquery
    var oldAjax = $.ajax;

    $.ajax = function(options) {
        console.log(options)
         // Do your magic.
         return oldAjax.apply($, arguments);

    }
    //need to use backbone,underscore here
});
```

But still i could not get it loaded into my application.Please advise.

Comment: I pointed out in my answer below that your `shim` for `jqueryajaxhandler` *is* a problem. It may not be the *only* problem, but it is a problem nonetheless. It is definitely wrong. So you should remove that. Also, your edit is still far from a [mcve]. There's nothing in your question right now that exercises your override.

Comment: @Louis Updated my question now. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mymotherland where is the entrypoint of your script from config?

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery` is already AMD compatible, so looks like you can't shim this dependency in this way.

From official documentation: 
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

> Remember: only use shim config for non-AMD scripts...

As a primitive workaround you could return another object like that:

```
return { ajax : $.ajax };
```

Or make it smarter if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Modules that call `define` do not need to use `shim`. If you do use `shim` with a module that calls `define` you get undefined behavior. So this could be the reason you are getting problems: remove your shim for `jqueryajaxhandler`.

Comment: I tried remove shim for jqueryajaxhandler, still not works